# Debugging an ASP.NET MVC application that uses EXT.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, extjs, controller

I'm developing a ASP.NET 4 MVC Application that uses EXT.NET.
I want to debug a method that is referenced in a directevent in a view.
When I press the button the method was invoked, but the debugger doesn't work.

Comment: checks whether the event that you invoke is not javascript

Comment: I press the button that has the direct event associated. No Javascript involved.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was correlated to publish configuration having release option enabled.
Set it to debug, the debug configuration rewors fine.